# Restful resources rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

What is the correct way to make this api 'restful'

I have a location,

```
GET location/:id
PUT location/:id
```

The spec has changed and now this location can have certain 'types' the client can update. One requirement is that the client get the allowed types (could be one of these from a fixed list - i.e.['urban', 'wilderness', 'private', etc..]) for all locations. This isn't a nested resource, its a column on the location table. I've implemented,

```
GET location/types_allowed
```

is there are better RESTFUL way?

Another example, a location can have neighbors, so I made GET `locations/neighbors`.  I'm having trouble understanding the nuances of REST beyond CRUD and nested resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a column as `types_allowed`, create a `type` resource and the relation can be like

```
location.rb
  belongs_to :type

type.rb
  has_many :locations
```

and with this your route file would be

```
resources :type do
  resources :location
end
```

Comment: Interesting, so if I want to do a PUT on the location I would do  PUT type/:id/location/:id  ?  Also a location can have many types or just one, the types are an enum and will not change

Comment: Yes you'd use that url to do a PUT, in the above example a `location` will have only one `type`, if a `location` needs to belong to more than one type then you should be using has_many on both sides, have a look at the guides here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: @whoaaallamapajama almost but not quite... think of a specified resource as a collection of things eg your location resource is a collection of locations. so if you are creating a new one, you are *PUT*ting a new location into the collection. Same with your `type` resource. So if you are creating a new `type` you would use: `PUT types, type_params`. If you then have a collection of locations for a specific `type` you'd be putting a location to that specific type's locations... thus `PUT types/:id/locations, location_params`

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, I feel that the conversation is a little off the rails of the original questions tho. A location has attributes and the client needs to know which options are allowed to update for this attribute . Say attribute A can only be [2,3,4]. What is a restful for the client to get the options for attribute A to the client @Subash Taryn East

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend against naming a model/column "type". That tends to break magic things inside of rails that you don't even know are there until you try that. It's one of those "undocumented features" :P

I'd instead recommend reading up on "single table inheritance" or "polymorphism" to figure out if either of these is right for you.

If not... then name something "kind" instead of "type" as it'll all work a lot better that way.

As to RESTful resources... you really can't go past the Rails Guides. If you follow the [routing guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html): (and all the other ones) you'll get an idea of how to do RESTful resources